# WPF localization issue

Tags: c#, wpf, localization, culture, wpflocalizationextension

For testing purpose, I'm trying to localize a dummy application, in order to see what match the best our needs.

I wanted to try [WPF Localization Extension](https://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com).

So I :

1. Created a whole new WPF application, created a main windows.
2. Added the references to WPF Localization Extension through nugget.
3. Created one resx named `Localization.resx` and one `Localization.fr.resx`
4. I Added in both resx a text for the "WelcomeText" key.
5. In main windows, I put:

   ```
   xmlns:lex="http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com"
   lex:LocalizeDictionary.DesignCulture="en"
   lex:ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultAssembly="LocalizedApplication"
   lex:ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultDictionary="Localization"
   ```

   In the Window declaration
6. I added one `TextBlock` within the grid:
   `<TextBlock Text="{lex:Loc WelcomeText}" />`

If I run the application, I've the text displayed in english.

Now I add the following in the App.cs constructor:

```
    public App():base()
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fr");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
    }
```

To test the application in FR. I rebuild and restart, but I still get the message in english.

So first: What did I do wrong?
Then: How should I change the current culture at runtime?

Answer (score 3):

In fact, I think I just found the answer.

It seems that it doesn't use the CurrentCulture and that you have to set it with:

```
LocalizeDictionary.Instance.Culture = new CultureInfo("fr");
```

Sorry for the issue